# uwp Caliburn.micro navigation

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro

How can I navigate to a screen stretched to the whole screen, to navigate to some kind of Image Viewer page?

Thanks

Comment: What have you done? Could you please provide your xaml code and c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to learn how to use `caliburn.micro` in UWP.

You could read the following three articles to learn how to use it.

[Using Caliburn Micro with Universal Windows app – The project setup](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-caliburn-micro-with-universal-windows-app-the-project-setup/)

[Using Caliburn Micro with Universal Windows app – Binding and actions](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-caliburn-micro-with-universal-windows-app-binding-actions/)

[Using Caliburn Micro with Universal Windows app – Navigation](http://blog.qmatteoq.com/using-caliburn-micro-with-universal-windows-app-navigation/)

> I have a Grid with images. When an image is clicked, how can I navigate to a screen stretched to the whole all, to navigate to some kind of Image Viewer page?

This issue should be about the `Navigation` of `caliburn.micro` in UWP. You could read the above third article for details.